# Django signup form doesn't submit data or save in database or valid and invalid errors working

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, backend

$ I was trying to submit this following codes , it never submit or saved in database or give any reaction , even the warnings or (valid and invalid of bootsrap5.2 in not working) , i need support, thank you alot

$ this is code in the (views.py),

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login as signin
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
# This can replace the 3 uppers
from .forms import SignUpForm
def signup(request):  
form = SignUpForm()
if request.method == 'POST' and 'btnsignup2' in request.POST:
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        user = form.save()
        signin(request, user)
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()

context = {                
    'basic': 
        {'main': 'Project',
            },
    'form': form
}
return render(request, 'accounts/signup-dj.html', context)
```

$ this is code in the (forms.py)

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login as signin
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=250, required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput())
class Meta:
    model = User 
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2']
```

$ this is (urls.py)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('login', views.login, name="login"),
path('signout', views.signout, name="signout"),
path('signup', views.signup, name="signup"),
]
```

$ this is code in the (HTML)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %} 
{% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock %}<!-- | Page-title-->
{% block content %}
<div class="signup-form">
<div class="container-signup w-50">
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <br>
    {% include 'parts/alerts.html' %}
    <form class="row g-3" metho="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %} 
        {% include 'includes/form.html' %}


        <button type="submit" name="btnsignup2" class="btn main-btn w-100 rounded-pill">
            Create New User</button>
        <p class="mt-3">
            You Already Have Account at {{basic.main}} ? <a href="{% url 'login'
          %}">Login</a>
        </p>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at the HTML I can see that here:

```
<form class="row g-3" metho="POST" action="">
```

you have a typo in `metho="POST"`, it should be `method="POST"`, and assign the url of the endpoint to `action`, like `action="/signup"`.